# Magento 2 curreny import issues

Tags: magento2, import, currency

Currently all Magento default imports of currency are not working for a fresh demo install of Magento 2.2.4 and a couple of my active Magento 2.2.X projects.

I've tried with Yahoo Finance Exchange, WebserviceX and Fixer.io, but all return errors:

**Yahoo Finance Exchange**

> We can't retrieve a rate from http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&q=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.xchange+where+pair+in+%28%22USDCHF%22%2C%22USDCNY%22%2C%22USDEUR%22%2C%22USDHRK%22%2C%22USDKMF%22%2C%22USDUSD%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys for CHF.

**Webservicex**

> We can't retrieve a rate from http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=CHF.

**Fixer.io**

> We can't retrieve a rate from
>   http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=HRK&symbols=EUR,HRK for EUR.

I've tried testing by changing the base currency and additional currencies in `Configuration -> General -> Currency setup` but every time it's showing the above errors for all services.

Seems that the Fixer.io API endpoint is deprecated. And the new endpoint can't be used without a Fixer.io account. I guess Magento didn't adjust the endpoint yet...

Webservicex is returning a "Page not found" JSON response and Yahoo is returning a null value for the query.

I presume their APIs changed and Magento didn't adjust to the changes yet...

Can anyone suggest or provide a quick fix for one of the services?

**EDIT**
After installing the shopgo module for additional currency import services you get Google Finance as a new import option.

But it returns this error:

> We can't retrieve a rate from http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=CHF.

When using the direct link you get this error:

[image]

I presume it's generic since my server isn't "sending automated requests to Google Finance API".

Answer (score 1):

If you visit that URL, you'll notice it says:

{"code":"PAGE_NOT_FOUND","message":"Page not found"}
Not good. If you then go to webservicex.net and scroll through its list of API, you'll notice that none refer to currency conversion. Also, not good.

If you web search for currency import in Magento 2, you'll come to this shopgo module, which says:

> Magento 2.0's default and only currency import service WebserviceX
>   tends to go down from time to time. And sometimes, it returns empty
>   results for some currencies.

Three times the charm: webservicex.net is probably not going to work. Try installing the module from shopgo, which uses other providers.

Comment: I tried installing the module, but no luck. It added Google finance and another Yahoo Finance import option, but unfortunately both of them also return an error when importing. The module was last updated 3 years ago, so no wonder it doesn't work... Thanks for try though.

Comment: Whats is the error you are getting?

Comment: I edited my question with the Google Finance error

Answer (score 1):

Create free account : https://fixer.io

Copy your API Acces Key

Edit: [root]/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency/Import/FixerIo.php

Replace: const CURRENCY_CONVERTER_URL = 'http://api.fixer.io/latest?base={{CURRENCY_FROM}}&symbols={{CURRENCY_TO}}';

By: const CURRENCY_CONVERTER_URL = 'http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=**YourAPIkey**&base={{CURRENCY_FROM}}&symbols={{CURRENCY_TO}}';

With Your API key

Comment: +1 for this, but unfortunately the free plan of Fixer.io provides only € as the base currency, which is a problem for my stores since they use another base currency. And the basic plan of Fixer, which provides all base currencies costs 10$/month. I appreciate the answer though!